# Count function within a Case When condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Could anyone explain to me the difference between the SQL statements below? I can see there is a difference but I can't nail down the exact conditions which can make them produce different results. By the way, I'm thinking the `distinct` clause doesn't make a difference on the `user.id` field since all the ids are already unique. The purpose of the query is to count the number of unique (non-empty) last names. If the last name is empty, then count as unique.

I suppose the general case for this problem would be the use of an aggregate function within a case-when statement.

Count within Case-When:

```
SELECT 
    (case when (substr(u.name,40,40) <> '                                        ')
        then count(distinct(substr(u.name,40,40)))
        else count(u.id) 
    end) as "LAST_NAME",
FROM 
    users u
GROUP BY
    substr(u.name,40,40)
```

Case-When within Count:

```
SELECT 
    count (distinct case when (substr(u.name,40,40) <> '                                        ')
        then substr(u.name,40,40)
        else to_char(u.id)
    end) as "LAST_NAME",
FROM 
    users u
GROUP BY
    substr(u.name,40,40)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `user.id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, these queries are identical semantically, though they are likely to produce different execution plans.

They will return `1` for all non-empty last names, since you are counting distinct values of the group-by expession within its group, which, by definition, will be exactly one.

For empty last names, the first query will essentialy return `COUNT(u.id)` and the second one will return `COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(u.id))`, which, given that `u.id` is unique, is the same.

I believe you need to remove `GROUP BY` from the second query:

```
SELECT  count (distinct case when (substr(u.name,40,40) <> '                                        ')
        then substr(u.name,40,40)
        else to_char(u.id)
    end) as "LAST_NAME",
FROM 
    users u
```